# How can we import/include MathQuill in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mathquill

I'm trying to test my application using Jestjs. Since some of the buttons in my application are MathQuill math fields, I need to be able to somehow include/import MathQuill for testing the button presses using Jestjs. I've looked up a lot of resources online and I can't seem to find a way to do this.

If you've come across a similar dead end and happen to have resolved it, could you please give me some pointers on possible solutions/workarounds which I can try out? Thank you!

Edit:

I'm doing something like this in JavaScript:

```
let MQ = MathQuill.getInterface(MathQuill.getInterface.MAX);
```

I'm trying to figure out how to import the MathQuill library.

Comment: can you provide an example of the code you are trying to test?