# How to import mathQuill span data to a Svg

Tags: javascript, html, svg, mathquill

[image: screenshot of the program]

I'm creating a scientific formula generator for a website using [mathQuill library](http://mathquill.com/) in node, javaScript.
I'm using just a span as exactly the mathQuill documentation says as below

```
<p class = "mt-3">Type math below</p>
<span id = "math-field"></span>
<label for = "latex">LaTeX : </label>
<input id = "latex"/>
```

I've downloaded the mathQuill 0.10.1 version and here is the stylesheet and script

```
<!-- mathQuill css -->
<link href = "../static/libraries/mathquill-0.10.1/mathquill-basic.css" rel = "stylesheet">

<!-- mathQuill script -->
<script src = "../static/libraries/mathquill-0.10.1/mathquill.min.js"></script>
```

and here are the scripts

```
const MQ = MathQuill.getInterface (2)
const latex_span = $ ('#latex')
const mathField = MQ.MathField (document.getElementById ('math-field'), {
    spaceBehavesLikeTab: true, // configurable
    handlers: {
        edit: function () {
        latex_span.val (mathField.latex ()); // simple API
        }
    }
)}

latex_span.keyup (() => {
    mathField.latex (latex_span.val ())
)}
```

All of these works fine, but I want to import the generated HTML code inside the span tag (#latex) into an SVG file. after I want to add this SVG to  [paperjs](http://paperjs.org/) canvas.I'm stuck with convert this HTML code inside the span tag to an SVG file. Is there any possible way to do that?
I've only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824812/how-can-we-import-include-mathquill-in-javascript) question in the StackOverflow to export this span tag to an SVG file. There was nothing in the mathQuill documentation and anywhere. At least can someone give me a link to refer

[image: span tag of latex]

thanks in advance!